# Killing all the activities before running second test with Espresso on Android

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I'm using Cucumber and Espresso. I have the following feature file:

```
Feature: From Main to Profile 

  Background:
    Given User is registered
    And User is logged in

  @ios @android   Scenario: User can navigate from the home screen to the profile screen
    Given User is on the home screen
    When User taps Profile
    Then User is navigated to the profile screen

  @ios @android   Scenario: User can navigate from the profile screen back to the home screen
    Given User is on the Profile screen
    When User taps back
    Then User is navigated back to the home screen
```

in the step defining `Then User is navigated to the profile screen` I had to add a `pressBack` otherwise the starting of the `MainActivity` for the second test was not working (it was timing out) and I could see on the emulator that the `ProfileActivity` was still shown.

This is the `steps` class:

```
public class MainActivitySteps extends BaseActivitySteps {

    public static final int PROFILE_BUTTON_ID = R.id.tvProfile;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);
    @Rule
    public GrantPermissionRule permissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        activityTestRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
        activity = activityTestRule.getActivity();
        Intents.init();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        activityTestRule.finishActivity();
        Intents.release();
    }

    @Given("^User is on the home screen")
    public void userIsAtMainScreen() {
        assertTrue(activity.findViewById(R.id.btnRecordTrip).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @When("^User taps Profile")
    public void userTapsProfile() {
        // wait for view to become visible
        userTaps(PROFILE_BUTTON_ID);
    }

    @Given("^User is on the Profile screen")
    public void userIsAtProfileScreen() {
        userTaps(PROFILE_BUTTON_ID);

    }

    @Then("^User is navigated to the profile screen")
    public void userIsNavigatedToTheProfileScreen() {
        intended(hasComponent(ProfileActivity.class.getName()));
        pressBack();
    }

    @When("^User taps back")
    public void userTapsBack() {
        pressBack();
    }

    @Then("^User is navigated back to the home screen$")
    public void userIsNavigatedBackToTheHomeScreen() {
        userIsAtMainScreen();
    }

}
```

I have found [this](https://gist.github.com/bootstraponline/ce2ce790008980fc1f04d33b9baba7d7) that might be useful but I find surprising that I need to do it by myself: it seems to me such a basic feature.
Is there a better way to kill the `ProfileActivity` after the first test?

Comment: Did you get a way to do this? Currently I am so stuck in getting this thing. I want to reset my app each time before starting a new test

Comment: @Emjey you can use the orchestrator. Just Google it or check https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html#using-android-test-orchestrator.

Comment: Yes but when i do that it immediately says me no tests found and when i remoce that my tests starts to run. Why is that

Comment: When it says no test found it is likely to be a problem with the configuration. Have you checked that you are importing the correct version? There is for example different version for AndroidX

Comment: `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'` // for instrumentation tests
    `androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'` // for instrumentation tests

 `testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`

        `testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'`

Along with this I am inputting test options as orchestrator.

Comment: Should I be using the exact same version mentioned in the documentation? And also AndroidX? I was quite skeptical as without these my tests run and I kinda was afraid to mess it up

Comment: @Emjey  I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'm using:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "an androidx library:1.0.0"
    ...
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
    }

    testOptions {
        animationsDisabled true
        execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'

        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources true
        }
    }
}
```

So please notice that I'm using AndroidX for both the dependencies and the Orchestrator.

Since you are not using AndroidX you need to use `execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'`.

The `testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'` is not strictly necessary if you just want to kill the activities.

Comment: Is `implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"` needed?

Comment: I am using `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` and all other things that you have mentioned xcept for legacy in the dependency. I still get test not found

Comment: This is the command that gets launched `adb shell CLASSPATH=$(pm path android.support.test.services) app_process / android.support.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -r -w -e targetInstrumentation com.xyz.android.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner   -e debug false -e class 'com.xyz.android.Profile' -e clearPackageData true android.support.test.orchestrator/android.support.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator`
Waiting for process to come online...`

Started running tests
Test running failed: No test results

Comment: It's not needed if you don't want to use AndroidX. In that case, you need to use ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR instead of ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR

Comment: Yes i did that, but then when i did it and synced it says no tests found. I had provided additional comments as well on the command it is executing. I do have @Test annotations as well. I am not sure why it is not recognised

Comment: and `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0` doesn't have to do with the orchestrator. I put it there to say that I was using AndroidX

Comment: I am mentioning Junit4runner in the test class and in the command it is Junit runner is it because of that?

Comment: In most cases the error is misleading. The problem is not that it can't find the tests but that something else went wrong. From the command line I just run `./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest`

Comment: `com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[Pixel_XL_API_28_2(AVD) - 9] FAILED 
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).`
---
I am using `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)`

Comment: right, that's one of the most misleading error-message ever. Try to go up in the logs to check whether you see other errors although in most cases you can't see very much. You just need to be sure that you have configured everything consistently. Considering that you say that the tests run without the orchestrator I would guess that something is wrong in the way you are configuring it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205450/discussion-between-emjey-and-kingston).

Comment: Cannot connect to android.support.test.orchestrator.OrchestratorService